# Real life experience developing with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a project where we have to take the decision soon whether to invest in our current technology stack to improve it and make it more flexible to support our time to market (LAMP based stack) or whether to change to a different stack in the hope that it would make our development faster, more efficient and possibly more fun.

One framework we're looking at is Meteor. So I'm wondering: Does anyone have real life experience with starting or shifting a medium-sized project to Meteor (3 developers, couple of hundred active users, mostly short-lived small pieces of user-generated content that are viewed by all users and need to be updated instantly)? Do you have metrics on productivity, code quality, code efficiency that you could share? Or just overall a feeling for how it went? How happy are you with Meteor when working using it for more than just a week or two? How is maintainability over a longer period? How well does it scale up?

Would appreciate any insight!

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. I strongly advise you to go to somewhere like www.reddit.com/r/meteor where it's much more suited for these kinds of questions!

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to be as fact based as possible to keep this objective:
I switched from Django to Meteor, PostGreSQL to MongoDB.

Switching stacks has a huge cost. A new language, syntax, patterns, and maybe even IDE. Online courses to be taken, a solid node.js foundation, curiosity about io.js, ES6, and Mongo 3.0. A refresher on how JavaScript treats Dates and numbers, and how to use JavaScript to query mongo.
On top of that, you'll want your developers to peak under the hood to see the Meteor magic so they understand fibers, reactivity, DDP, and minimongo. All these things will cost each developer at LEAST 160 hours, yet are necessary to be a competent developer. Skip these steps, and you've got a team of monkeys pulling levers.

To answer your questions:
Productivity? It will hit rock bottom along with code quality. Then slowly climb, and possibly exceed the previous mark (IF it's something the developers enjoy). This is because client & server are in the same language & just a file away. Debugging messages & stack traces are pretty good & hot code reloads, although still not great, are good.

Code quality has absolutely nothing to do with the framework.

Code efficiency is good because reactivity in handled behind the scenes most of the time and fibers makes it possible to write server code in a synchronous fashion. This increases code readability.

Maintainability is another word for code quality.

Scalability is more of a question about node.js, but will work for the VAST majority of projects. An honest critique of node's shortcomings is here: https://medium.com/code-adventures/farewell-node-js-4ba9e7f3e52b

Comment: that's a good point about learning a bit about how Meteor works internally.  Evented Mind https://www.eventedmind.com/  has a lot of good classes about the fundamental concepts behind meteor.

Comment: Agreed! That video on fibers & futures is the best of its kind. Although careful with the older videos since there have been a ton of changes since 2012. From personal experience, learning something & then discovering it was outdated is really discouraging...